# Multiple special prices for a single product

Tags: magento2.3, import, special-price

I've been asked about having the possibility to have multiple date ranges in the advanced pricing section at once so that my client can bulk update all the products with all of their promo periods throughout the year.

Since Magento only has one single special price and special price date range, I wonder if any of you have dealt with a similar issue in the past and how did you resolve it, or if there's ant third-party module with such functionality.

The approach I'm thinking so far is importing a custom CSV with SKU-special price-special price range that would be read daily and, depending on each SKU and date range would update each product's special price.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
Antonio

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for adding multiple special prices for a single product in the database, we couldn't use product attributes because we are using EAV. We can create a new table on the database with fields like special price, date start, date end, product id. Using the plugin, we can get a special price based on the current date and show it on the product page. You also need to take care of price change on add to cart, checkout, admin order, invoice, shipment emails. For updating table values, you can give an admin grid with CSV import, manually adding and editing option for a special price so clients can view the prices for upcoming promotions.